# Javascript division error using division operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, javascript-objects

This output should be true.but it give false always.

```
Number.isInteger(parseFloat('134965.83') / parseFloat('0.01'))
```

Comment: please test on chrome console itself

Comment: `13496582.999999998` is float right ?

Comment: It's not an integer, as it's a float...

Comment: parseFloat() always returns a floating number. So how can Number.isInteger() be true?

Comment: @all  if you saying it always false then how come  the below value becomes true. my simple doubt. please try it on the console.
Number.isInteger(parseFloat('134965.82') / parseFloat('0.01'))

Comment: @RayonDabre yeh that is my doubt why the value is coming as like this 13496582.999999998.

test1:
134965.83/0.01
=13496582.999999998
test2:
134965.82/0.01
=13496582

Answer (score 2):

Floating point arithmetic in Javascript is [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript) and in [general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) as well.

It has nothing to do with division, it will return false if you don't do division since you are checking float value.

`Number.isInteger(parseFloat('134965.83') / parseFloat('0.01'))` translates to `Number.isInteger(13496582.999999998)` -> `false`

Check these [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger#Examples).

```
Number.isInteger(parseFloat('134965.83') )// outputs false without division
```

As per the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-isinteger)

> If Type(argument) is not Number, return false.
>
> If floor(abs(argument)) ≠ abs(argument), return false.

Comment: Expected value after division is `13496583`..That is why OP is expecting Integer..

Comment: @RayonDabre only if float point arithmetic worked that way :) try this `parseFloat(1111.1)/parseFloat(0.1)`

Comment: Expected value after division is 13496583..That is why OP is expecting Integer..
Exactly what you said..i am expecting the output as integer if it exactly divides.

Comment: @shamil In that case you should give `Math.round(Number('134965.83') / Number('0.01'))`

Comment: @gurvinder372 very thanks. 
if(Number.isInteger(parseFloat('134965.80') / parseFloat('0.01'))) 
Any alternative for the above one.. which is if condition. the suggestion that you given do not fit over here.

Comment: @shamil this is precisely the point. Please read the first line of my answer.  Floating point arithmetic may give some strange results. Try `11.5 - 11.01` on your chrome

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the outcome of the division is not an integer but something like `13496582.999999998`.

Some floating numbers require a very small precision that is limited by the data type used. For example, the number `1/3` can never be expressed entirely as `0.333333333333` because there is a limitation to the data type size. Therefore there will always be a tiny rounding error involved in floating operations.

Edit: In response to the comment asking for a recommendation on how to deal eith this, actually there are [several possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). It depends on the context and on accuracy required.

In short, to overcome this use a very small constant [Number.EPSILON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON) ([see also this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)) and use it in comparisons. *Disclaimer*: this is just a quick example, read extensively the implications on the links provided.

```
var myIsInteger = function(n) {
  return (n % 1) > Number.EPSILON
};
```

We effectively check that the residual of the division with 1 is within the constant.

Comment: yes. please let me know how to overcome this.. i expecting the behaviour as like 134965.82/0.01  for 134965.83/0.01

Comment: Provided recommendation.

Comment: very Thanks 
if(Number.isInteger(parseFloat('134965.83') / parseFloat('0.01')){
  console.log("true");
}
else{
   console.log("false");
   //do Nothing
}
how to alternate your suggestion with above one.

Comment: Welcome. `if (myIsInteger(parseFloat('134965.83') / parseFloat('0.01'))) console.log('bingo');`

Comment: function load(){if (myIsInteger(parseFloat('134965.82') / parseFloat('0.01'))) {
 console.log("true");
}
else{
 console.log("false");
}}

load();
Answer : false

Comment: `((parseFloat('134965.83') / parseFloat('0.01')) % 1) > Number.EPSILON` returns `true`, at least in my console.

Comment: ((parseFloat('134965.83') / parseFloat('0.01')) % 1) > Number.EPSILON
true
((parseFloat('134965.82') / parseFloat('0.01')) % 1) > Number.EPSILON
false
please conclude me on this..
both should have same response right..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107011/discussion-between-wtower-and-shamil).

Answer (score 0):

parseFloat('134965.83') / parseFloat('0.01') = 13496582.999999998

And when Number.isInteger(13496582.999999998) will always return false